# My .htaccess pretty url not working which is in localhost (local machine with xampp)

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite this url :
   `http://localhost/blog/post.php?id=48` 
into 
    `http://localhost/blog/post/48`
which is in localhost of my xampp.
I have created .htaccess file and wrote the below code to work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have tried redirection and all other stuff. Everything is working but my rewrite rule alone not working. I've searched and tried all options but i couldn't succeed. Plz anyone help me out on this!!

Comment: do not pollute tags. Your question was not PHP related at all. tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally its working with below code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/ # This is the thing which made me struck with this
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1 [NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^post` is your problem, this implies that post is the first part of your path, which it's not - `blog` is. Have you tried `^blog/post...`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^blog/post/([0-9]+)/?$ blog/post.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have done it too. But no use..Still it shows same url! is this due to any config problem in my xampp?

Comment: Ahh yeah, that makes sense. I think my answer was slightly wrong anyway - I've edited it with what I believe would have worked, but your way is perfectly valid too :)